# Running queries once only

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have an application which contains 2 buttons.

Button 1 gives the result by this query:

```
select * from tbl1;
```

Button 2 gives the result by this queries:

```
select * from tbl1;
select * from tbl2;
```

So what's happening is that I have to run `select * from tbl1` twice, Once for button 1 and once again for button 2.

Is it possible to run both queries once when button 1 is clicked, but only show the results from `tbl1`, and then show the results from `tbl2` when button 2 is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, cache the result. Store it into a variable (a *collection* like List) then use it to display result instead of *re-evaluating* the query.

Comment: Store it into a local variable ?

Comment: it should be stored in a datatable

Comment: yes, I mean a class level variable. it's also local, there is no global in C#

Comment: @SajadLfc is it a rule ? I would prefer creating a class and store my values into a strongly typed list

Comment: @Selman22 Class level variable is never meant as `local variable`. They are called as `Instance Fields`.

Answer (score 1):

store it in a `List<T>` to achieve what you need

Comment: @MarcGravell: i didn't get you,pls can you explain to me

Comment: `DataTable` was a transitional API introduced in .NET 1.0 (IIRC) to help people migrate off COM code with ADO recordsets. That was well over a decade ago. There are **vanishingly** few good scenarios to use `DataTable` today (the main one of which is if you are writing a tool that is not schema-bound, like an ad-hoc query tool, like [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)). Just about any alternative is **far, far** preferable. A `List<T>`, for example - populated by an ORM or micro-ORM.

Comment: @MarcGravell: edited my answer,after your suggestion,thankyou