# Best practice for data properties when creating an unbound usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm creating my own user control that uses Devexpress `xtraTreeList`. The control works in unbound mode and gets data by `readXML()`;
I want to set the data fields in the most flexible and correct way.

What I did now is made `InitData();` method where I populate the data-source with hard-coded column values like that:

```
private DataTable dt;

public MbsTreeList()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitData();
}

private void InitData()
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("eventID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("parentID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("startTime", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("duration",typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("status", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("timedByUser", typeof(bool));
    dt.Columns.Add("eventType", typeof(Int32));            
}
```

Is this a good practice or is it totally wrong and there better ways to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is better to create a class according to your XML schema,  populate `List<YourClass>` by values from XML and use this `List<YourClass>` instead of `DataTable`:

> DataTable was a transitional API introduced in .NET 1.0 (IIRC) to help
>   people migrate off COM code with ADO recordsets. That was well over a
>   decade ago. There are vanishingly few good scenarios to use DataTable
>   today (the main one of which is if you are writing a tool that is not
>   schema-bound, like an ad-hoc query tool, like data explorer). Just
>   about any alternative is far, far preferable. A List, for example -
>   populated by an ORM or micro-ORM. © [Marc Gravell♦](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883171/running-queries-once-only/24883251#comment38650509_24883251)

You can create a class by yourself or use [Class from XML generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx).
For example, if you have the XML file like this:

```xml
<MyClass>
  <eventID>1</eventID>
  <parentID>0</parentID>
  <name>Some name</name>
  <startTime>Some startTime</startTime>
  <duration>Some duration</duration>
  <status>Some status</status>
  <timedByUser>true</timedByUser>
  <eventType>1</eventType>
</MyClass>
```

It will generate this class:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class MyClass
{

    private byte eventIDField;

    private byte parentIDField;

    private string nameField;

    private string startTimeField;

    private string durationField;

    private string statusField;

    private bool timedByUserField;

    private byte eventTypeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte eventID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte parentID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parentIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string startTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.startTimeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.startTimeField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string duration
    {
        get
        {
            return this.durationField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.durationField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public bool timedByUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this.timedByUserField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.timedByUserField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte eventType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eventTypeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eventTypeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just need to change the types of some properties and fields to the appropriate types.
To populate a `List<MyClass>` by values you can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class or `LINQ`.
Here is example with `LINQ`:

```
string xml = @"
<MyClass>
    <eventID>1</eventID>
    <parentID>0</parentID>
    <name>Some name</name>
    <startTime>Some startTime</startTime>
    <duration>Some duration</duration>
    <status>Some status</status>
    <timedByUser>true</timedByUser>
    <eventType>1</eventType>
</MyClass>
<MyClass>
    <eventID>2</eventID>
    <parentID>0</parentID>
    <name>Some another name</name>
    <startTime>Some another startTime</startTime>
    <duration>Some another duration</duration>
    <status>Some another status</status>
    <timedByUser>false</timedByUser>
    <eventType>2</eventType>
</MyClass>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var dataSource = doc.Elements("MyClass")
    .Select<XElement, MyClass>(
        (item) =>
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();

            myClass.eventID = int.Parse(item.Element("eventID").Value);
            myClass.parentID = int.Parse(item.Element("parentID").Value);
            myClass.name = item.Element("name").Value;
            myClass.startTime = item.Element("startTime").Value;
            myClass.duration = item.Element("duration").Value;
            myClass.status = item.Element("status").Value;
            myClass.timedByUser = bool.Parse(item.Element("timedByUser").Value);
            myClass.eventType = int.Parse(item.Element("eventType").Value);

            return myClass;
        })
    .ToList<MyClass>();
```

Now you can use this `dataSource` variable for your purposes.

Comment: thank for the detailed answer nempoBu4! I'll have to do some experiments with Lists and Serialization! and didn't fully got the advantages over using a Datatable yet.